# Timezone conversion to UTC in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Is it possible to specify timezone in converting string to date in MariaDB.

In oracle, i am doing with something like below

```
cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr') at time zone 'UTC' as date)
```

Comment: Show an example input and output for your conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `CONVERT_TZ()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` (and maybe other functions) in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html